# Java - Android Studio - HttpURLConnection Post to PC PHP file

Tags: php, android, networking, local, device

My application works on my PC's Java Netbeans, posting variables to a local php page, echoing the post.

the PHP script looks like this:

```
echo 'VAR' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["post"]) . 'END' ;
```

With the root :C:\xampp\htdocs\urlct2ws

I am trying to achieve this same functionality using Android Studio, running the application on my Android Device. (both devices connected to the same network)

My code below attempts the connection when a button is pressed.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //predefined code - Start
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Predefined Code - End

        //Button Actions - Start
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCon);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String display = "";

                CallAPI caller = new CallAPI();
                display = caller.execute().toString();
                makeToast(display);
            }
        });
        //Button Actions - End

    }

    public void makeToast(String text) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    public class CallAPI extends AsyncTask <String, String , String >{

        public CallAPI(){
        }

        @Override protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            String response = "";

            try{
                String urlString = "http://10.0.0.21/urlct2ws/index.php";
                String data = "post=name";

                URL url = new URL (urlString);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true); //allows writing to the
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                urlConnection.connect();


                OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(data);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                //Post Code - End

                //Receiving Post Response - Start
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response = response + inputLine;
                }
                in.close();
                //Receiving Post Response - End


            }catch (Exception e){


            }


            return response;
        }


    }

}
```

Also i do have the following in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

The code seems to connect to the file, but the response is "com.example.javaurl.MainActivity$CallAPI@ (7 character code) "

Comment: First: `caller.onPreExecute();
                caller.doInBackground();`. You are not supposed to call those member functions yourself. Remove those calls. Replace by `caller.execute();`.

Comment: `makeToast(inputLine);` You cannot display Toast()s in doInBackground.

Comment: You have a NetworkOnMainThreadException or other exceptions which make your app crash. Why didnt you tell?

Comment: What is the name of the php script? Where is the .php extension?

Comment: @blackapps - Yes :D

I changed my bad practices, (My function calls and toasts); thank you for the clarification.
I also added the file name and extension as you said, it now seems to connect.
You mentioned there was an error, my application does not crash.

However, now instead of returning my post variable, it returns "com.example.javaurl.MainActivity$CallAPI@numbers"

Comment: Please adapt your code here too. Show us what you do.

Comment: You are not listening. Change `display = caller.execute().toString();` to `caller.execute();`.

Comment: `response = response + inputLine;` change to `response  += inputLine +"\n";`.

Comment: Dont leave that catch block empty. Print the stacktrace and add e.getMessage() to response string.

Comment: Thank you again. I am not sure not to indicate that you solved my issues, but your changes allows the successful communication now. This post is solved. Thanks again for your timely accurate response @blacksapps